# Support for different devices (action bar, left nav)

Tags: android

I noticed that for older devices running the FB application it doesn't have action bar or the slide-in left nav. Is it common practice to have 2 different releases? Or is the same app built to accomodate all versions the best thing to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

honestly if you were developing an app for Android 2.0+ and trying to implement a universal navigation system, IMO I'd just implement [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/), it conforms to the [google ui design guidelines](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html).

having different navigation base, on different android versions or devices, could confuse users when they upgrade, plus it will save you some coding and make your project more simple.

Answer (score 0):

OK got some answers from Professional Android 4 Application Development. 
Best practice according to the book seems to be checking for the version at runtime, then decide on an implementation, whether it's a layout or an activity. may be with an interface so that it's a better design.

Parallel activities and fragments are good, where fragments are decided on run time or activities are chosen at run-time based on version.

Don't rely on exception handling because Android does it slowly.